# What Selenium version is currently the most stable?

Tags: selenium, stability

My project's tests were written when Selenium 2.0a_ (Alpha versions) were available, and I want to upgrade Selenium to a more recent version. One good reason for this is that the old version does not work with recent Chrome versions. Other reasons are the many bug fixes, especially the IEDriver rewrite.

I tried using version 2.11.0, but there's a significant bug there, and it's been around for a while. The bug ([issue 2513](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2513)) throws random exceptions and apparently happens at least since version 2.6.0. There's a workaround, but it's not applicable for me. The bug is quite serious, tests just fail randomly.

I'm leaning toward trying version 2.5.0. Before investing time and effort, does anyone know of any major problem with this version?

More generally, what Selenium version you consider the most stable, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with the upgrades to selenium we have seen some stability issues too.. We experienced good stability with 2.5 and now we have moved on to 2.9 and the tests are relatively stable as much as it was in 2.5.

Do let me know how things work out for you?

Comment: Awesome! Good to know.. Though I would still recommend u upgrade once in a while..

Answer (score 0):

The [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) versions mentioned in [*CHANGELOG*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) are always well-tested before release and are stable enough to be used for test automation and test execution.

> [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium version [3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) is so far most stable version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).